# Splitting a string using regex at exactly one space

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to split a string using spaces but only if there is one space.

For example I have the following.

```
String s = "THIS IS A  TEST";
```

I want to take the result "THIS", "IS", "A  TEST". How to form the regex to do the job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use lookarounds:

```
(?<!\s)(\s)(?!\s)
```

This regex matches space that's not followed and not preceded by a space.

In Java, it'll look:

```
"THIS IS A  TEST".split("(?<!\\s)(\\s)(?!\\s)");
```

Explanation:

- The regex `(?<!a)b` matches "b" that's not *preceded* by an "a"
- The regex `b(?!a)` matches "b" that's not *followed* by an "a"

Further reading:

- [Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Answer (score 1):

Since the argument to split() is a regular expression, you can look for one or more spaces (" +") instead of just one space (" ").

> String[] array = s.split(" +");

You can also add and argument to limit the number of slips you want to split the string into.

> String[] array = s.split(" +", N );

Where N is the number of splits you want to divide the string into.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this regex which uses word boundaries.

```
string.split("\\b\\s\\b");
```